# how hide extension of my php files

Tags: php, apache

I`m trying to hide my php files extension in my hosted server.i add following code segment in .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

but when i try, it is not working. also i tried to do the same thing in my localhost.it is also not working properly.

so do i have to make any other changes to work on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for this is to first:
1. Convert all your .html files to .php
2. Make a .htaccess to hide all known .php extensions

E.g:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

NOTE: If you already have the `RewriteEngine on` command on top of your .htaccess file, no need of writing it when making new commands.

This method yet is ineffective because when you access localhost/login.php, it would redirect to localhost/login.

So you must do that with php in the individual files!.